# React - Virtualized list of Formik Forms

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, formik

So, I need to create a list of Formik Forms on a page. The user needs to be able to edit each form and be able to click on a submit button which will take each form's values turn convert that into an array of objects that are sent to the backend for processing.

Each form is rather big and has a lot of elements within it, having more than 4 slows down the page dramatically. So, I used react-window to get around this problem, now there can be many forms, and the page runs smoothly, since they are rendered in on demand.

I now have the problem of, how do I save the state of the form when a user scrolls aways from the form and come back to it, it can be initialised to the same values the user left it with before submission.

I have tried making use of the Formik innerRef prop, but when something is de-rendered, so is its ref, so I can't persist that. I have tried using a state variable that holds the state changes, when the form values are changed, that could work, but the form looses focus due to the re-render. I have tried using a Mutation Oberserver Hook that checks when the component leaves the DOM, this causes too many re-renders as I need to know the form values being changed, the same thing goes for the clean-up method in the useEffect hook.

I have also tried many variations of these options.

Is there any reference that anybody knows of that I could look at, or hopefully someone has needed to do this sort of thing before?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.